# How to detect left mouse click but not when the click occur on a UI Button component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My script makes a GameObject move on `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)`. Unfortunately, when I click on a `UI Button`, the move function is triggered causing the GameObject to move.

I do not want my GameObject to move when I press a button on the screen (UI element). I want to prevent GameObject from moving when the click is on a UI component such as `Button`? How can I remedy this? Also, I'd like to check if the mouse was clicked over ***specific*** UI elements (2 or 3 buttons)

Comment: How are you stopping it exactly?

Comment: post all your code responsible for movement

Comment: @ḞḹáḿíṅḡⱫỏḿƀíé You didn't understand the question. I have a script that makes a cube move when I release the mouse button. The problem: when I press a button in canvas, the cube moves no matter what. I do not want the cube to move when I press a canvas button.

Comment: have a read of this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, specifically the `Help others reproduce the problem` section

Comment: failing that you may find this tutorial helpful http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/player-character?playlist=17144

Comment: If you are pressing a UI button "in canvas", and clicking the mouse to do it, you will be performing a MouseUp event, so your code will execute telling the cube to move.

Comment: @ḞḹáḿíṅḡⱫỏḿƀíé That's the issue. How can I solve it? A UI button is not supposed to have an effect on the gameplay.

Comment: it is not the UI button that is affecting the gameplay, it is your mouse event

Comment: @xyLe_ I understand that. How can I press a UI button without having an effect on gameplay? I'm currently using `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)` to move the GameObject.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After reading your comment. What you need is [EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject.html) which checks if pointer is over UI. `true` when pointer is over UI, otherwise `false`. You can use it with '`!`' and run your rotation code only if the mouse is not over the UI.

For Desktop

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
{
    //Your code here
}
```

// For Mobile

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId))
{
    //Your code here
}
```

The solution above should work but there is a bug. When the mouse button is pressed over the `UI Button` then released outside of the `UI Button`, it will register as a click. So, basically, the solution works only when you click on `UI Button` and release on `UI Button`. If you release outside the `U Button`, the original problem will be back again.

The best solution is to use a temporary `boolean` value and check if button was originally pressed on a UI with `Input.GetMouseButtonDown`. That saved `boolean`, you can then use when the `Button` is released with `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)`. The solution below is provided to work with both Mobile and Desktop. Mobile tested and it works.

```
bool validInput = true;

private void Update()
{
    validateInput();

    #if UNITY_STANDALONE || UNITY_EDITOR

    //DESKTOP COMPUTERS
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && validInput)
    {
        //Put your code here
        Debug.Log("Valid Input");
    }
    #else

    //MOBILE DEVICES
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended && validInput)
    {
        //Put your code here
        Debug.Log("Valid Input");
    }
    #endif
}

void validateInput()
{
    #if UNITY_STANDALONE || UNITY_EDITOR
    //DESKTOP COMPUTERS
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
            validInput = false;
        else
            validInput = true;
    }
    #else
    //MOBILE DEVICES
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId))
            validInput = false;
        else
            validInput = true;
    }
    #endif
}
```

Comment: Does this script work for mobile devices?

Comment: @Dake Yes. It will on every platform. Try it and let me know

Comment: Thanks. "Simply attach the script below to the GameObject you want to detect click on" You're talking about my button?

Comment: @Dake No. Leave the `UI` button alone. You want to detect click on the GameObject you are moving? Then attach it to all those GameObjects you are moving.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. I have a Cube that rotates when the user releases their finger from the screen (thanks to a script with `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)`). ***Currently, when the user presses a UI button: the cubes rotates.*** I do not want that to happen. I want the user to to press the button without any

Comment: Did you understand? If you didn't, tell me so I can upload a simple GIF for you to understand.

Comment: I do not want to detect click on the GameObject I'm  moving.

Comment: @Dake Ok, got it. Your question is not clear. **My script makes a GameObject move on Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)**. So, that's what I thought. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: Hello, did you edit your answer?

Comment: @Dake Doing that now. Was answering another question.

Comment: No problem, take your time.

Comment: @Dake Just did. Check it out.

Comment: Why do you need `Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId)` ? And what is it?

Comment: @Dake It's the mobile version of the code. Input.GetTouch(0) gets touch of the of the first finger. fingerId is a unique index for the touch.

Comment: But `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)` also works for mobile.

Comment: @Dake It does. Don't use it for mobiles. Use it for mouse events. Use `Input.GetTouch` for mobile touch. I just tested the solution on mobile and it works. You can change it to Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) if you want.Although, I suggest you shouldn't.  You can now close this post since the problem is solved. Happy coding and dont forget to accept the answer

Comment: So simple.This is one of the best answers I've ever received. You deserve more than just an accepted answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Dake You are welcome. Fixed your question to be more descriptive so that it might help others in the future.

Comment: Hello again. `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()` checks if the mouse was clicked over any UI element. How can I check if the mouse was clicked over **specific** UI elements (buttons)? I would like to to use tags.

Comment: @Dake  create new question for that. Make sure to mention what UI components you want to detect clicks on. Also include a code that shows what you have tried.

Comment: There you go: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38211678/6542063

Answer (score 0):

I bet there are better solutions, but the first thing that comes to my mind is that:

Check if you are clicking an UI element, bevor moving your object on mouse up event.

You can check if you hit an UI element by using a `GraphicsRaycaster` to cast a ray on your mouse position. If it hits anything, then you are clicking on any canvas.

See: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-GraphicRaycaster.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using `Update()` method to handle mouse input with no proper conditions. I suggest you to change your code as use interaction with a UI element instead of mouse button down etc.

**Example:** create a big invisible *UI Panel* on all over the screen but must be behind everything else in *UI Canvas*. Then add a button component on it and control your `gameObject` movement by `OnClick()` event of this button. (please vote up to help others if it solves problem)