# Check if mouse was clicked over specific UI elements?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

`EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()` checks if the mouse was clicked over any UI element. How can I check if the mouse was clicked over ***specific*** UI elements (2 or 3 buttons)? I would like to use tags and keep using `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()` to read button clicks.

You register `Button` events with `Button.onClick.AddListener(() => callbackfunctionName());` in the OnEnable() function.

You then Unregister from the event in the `OnDisable()` function with  `Button.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();`

Since you need about 3 `Buttons`, instead of having multiple callback functions for the `Button`, I use only one function that takes `Button` as a parameter. I then use if statement to check which `Button` is pressed. This is the best way to do it as it reduces number of functions in your code.

Attach the Script below to a GameObject then Drag those Buttons to the `button1`,`button2` and `button3` slots.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonChecker: MonoBehaviour
{

    public Button button1;
    public Button button2;
    public Button button3;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        //Register Button Events
        button1.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(button1));
        button2.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(button2));
        button3.onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(button3));

    }

    private void buttonCallBack(Button buttonPressed)
    {
        if (buttonPressed == button1)
        {
            //Your code for button 1
        }

        if (buttonPressed == button2)
        {
            //Your code for button 2
        }

        if (buttonPressed == button3)
        {
            //Your code for button 3
        }
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        //Un-Register Button Events
        button1.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        button2.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        button3.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been scratching my head over how to integrate this with your previous [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38200330/6542063) . I just can't figure it out. I've edited my previous question to sum up what I need. Can you please edit your answer on my previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38198745/6542063)?

Comment: @Dake I don't see what's hard here. It's unnecessary to edit that answer. I looked at the answer, there is no function or variable name that are the-same. So you can just copy the old answer code and put it inside this code. It will also work. Which part are you having problems with? You can do that and post it on pastebin. Put the link here. I will take a look at tell you if there is anything wrong.

Comment: So, I should do this? `if (buttonPressed != button1)
        {if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended && validInput) 
   { //my moving code}}`

Comment: @Dake. No. No. I think I just confused you. Put the code in my last question in a new script. Then put this code in this answer in another script. Attach both script to a GameObject. I don't know what is suppose to happen when a UI Button is clicked but whatever that is should be put in one of the `if (buttonPressed == button1)
        {
            //Your code for button 1
        }` That's it. What are you having problem with?

Comment: That's wrong. You don't have to modify that. Tell me, what do you want to happen when the UI Buttons are clicked?

Comment: One button is for loading another scene and the other is for showing the leaderboard.

Comment: Why is that wrong to do? Again: it's a pseudo-code.

Comment: It doesn't matter if its a pseudo or not. It's still wrong.Do not modify the  `validateInput()` or the first code from my first answer. That should be working straight out of the box. That code is to prevent interference when  clicking on UI buttons. Simply create a new script called `ButtonChecker`. Copy the code from this answer and paste it there. Now, put your loading scene function in `if (buttonPressed == button1)
        {
            //Yourloading function
        }`

Comment: and your show leadership function in the `if (buttonPressed == button2)
        {
            //Your code for button 2
        }`. That's it. That should work. Don't forget to attach the `ButtonChecker` to gameobject.

Comment: Look, my screen is full of "invisible" UI elements. They're invisible so I can activate and deactivate them when I want to. The problem: when I touch or click the screen, my moving code is not called because I've clicked an invisible UI element.

Comment: That's why I want to check if the mouse was clicked over specific UI elements (the visible ones).

Comment: I'm still stuck. Some more help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116589/discussion-between-programmer-and-dake).

Comment: I've written a reply in chat.

Comment: I did what you said. I created a `ButtonChecker` script and attached it to a GameObject. Again, here's issue I'm encountering: when I touch or click the screen, my moving code is not called because I've clicked an invisible UI element.

Comment: @Dake That's what I wanted you to do. I just don't have enough time to waste. If you do it and it didn't work then we can find a fix. I will be back.

Comment: It's probably better if you uploaded an example project, my friend. This would make things much clearer and get messages across easier.

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out that the UI elements are of course located inside a canvas.

Comment: I will soon provide you with a link to my example project. Inside the canvas, you'll see "InvisibleButtons". When you click on those, the Cube doesn't move. Tell me if one of us did something wrong. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I've sent you both the scripts and an example project. I would appreciate a reply :) I'm afraid I'm running out of time...

Comment: Here's the code on pastebin.com as you requested! pastebin.com/G1gHz2BN

Comment: That's just a typo I made only on pastebin.com If you look in the project I uploaded, the typo's not there. Unity wouldn't even allow me to run the game.