# Inter-functional timing error (C#, Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 scripts (RunControl.cs and FireControl.cs) that depend on mouse click event.

**RunControl.cs** : Triggered by a button at the top of the screen. When clicked, the game stops.

**FireControl.cs** : Allows the character to fire when the mouse is clicked.

***Problem***: Since I have to click when I want to stop the game, first the character shoots and then the game stops. I tried the following codes for blocking but I couldn't block it.

```
//RunControll.cs
private void Start()
    {
        isRun = true;
    }
    public void OnButtonClick()
    {
        if(btn.image.sprite == runSprite)
        {
            btn.image.sprite = stopSprite;
            FindObjectOfType<FireControl>().isRun = false;
            isRun = false;
            
        }
        else
        {
            btn.image.sprite = runSprite;
            FindObjectOfType<FireControl>().isRun = true;
            isRun = true;
            
        }
    }
```

```
//FireControl.cs
private void Start()
    {
        isRun = true; //Controlled by RunControl.cs
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isRun)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
            {
                fire = true;
            }
            else
            {
                fire = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

!!! *Changing FireControl.cs to lateupdate didn't work*

Comment: Have you tried `Script Execution Order` in `PlayerSettings` and see if it works?

Comment: I didn't know we had an option to edit in this way. I did a little research after your comment and it seems like a method that will work.

Comment: Let me keep you informed of the improvements and I would appreciate it if you could turn your comment into a new answer depending on the situation.

Comment: [I added it like this](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/630380035039035404/871418275618230312/Ekran_Alnts.PNG) but it didn't work. I found a note in the [unity document](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html)-> **Note: The execution order specified in this settings window does not affect the order of functions marked with the RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod attribute. (You cannot specify an order for runtime initialization.)**

Comment: So It is better to change your design to handle all touch events in one place.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I guess I wanted to do a challenge for myself. Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a 'race condition' - which will happen first, disabling the game, or firing. A singleton GameManager class that keeps track of state and is updated by the OnClick and read by the FireControl would go a long way in cleaning up your code, but it would not fix the race condition.

I would take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38200330/2209181) to the question "How to detect left mouse click but not when the click occur on a UI Button component?"

Based off that answer you could update your FireControl to not fire when clicking over the button, which would avoid the race condition all together

```
    if (isRun)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
        {
            fire = true;
        }
        else
        {
            fire = false;
        }
    }
```

**Option 2 - Using RayCast**

Tag your button so it is identifiable, we'll say as "button". Then do a RayCast and check if pointer is over button, and if so - do not fire

```
var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
var overButton = false;

if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit)
{
    overButton = hit.collider.tag == "button";
}
else 
{
    overButton = false;
}

// Continue with your fire logic
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) && !overButton)
{
    // Fire
}
```

The above is a little messy and could be opitmized, but *should* work

Comment: I haven't tested that, so if it does not work, your best option would be to, as @AminSojoudi alluded to, handle the button click at the same point as the firing rather than through an OnClick handler. This can be done with ray casting and there are a number of tutorials out there. If the above does not work I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: I debugged the code in your suggestion. In your suggestion, the mouse returns false only when you go out of the game screen. But my requirement is that the stop button UI element is false when hovered over it. i am linking the status to the [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/630380035039035404/871508830687727646/scrn.jpg) ( red : output of your suggestion, green : status i need )

Comment: " If the above does not work I can point you in the right direction. " -> waiting for your suggestion

Comment: This should get you started: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1078490/using-raycast-to-see-if-button-clicked.html. You should be able to use raycast to determine when you are over your button, and not fire

Comment: Updated answer with a possible ray cast example